# Java - Selenium with PhantomJS for downloading a file from server

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

is there a way i can download a file from server using PhantomJS with selenium?? please help.
i have hear that this feature is not presently there in PhantomJS. but is there a workaround for this??
i have seen an issue that is open on #10052 which states that there is no feature yet in phantomJS for downloading or uploading files to server

**UPDATE**

refer - https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10052

is there a work around?

Comment: If the file is not binary (eg CSV) my answer here will work http://stackoverflow.com/a/31910804/74585