# Save Included Files

Tags: phantomjs

Running a PhantomJS script and it's going great, love it!  I'm using it to analyse malicious Javascript for behaviour and subsequent malicious downloads.

The one thing I'm stuck on... if a webpage pulls down subsequent files, how can I save them too?
Saving html/js is easy I can put that as a new page.  But I'm more interested in PDF/SWF and others, things I can't parse.

I've tried:
[How to download a csv file using PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564215/how-to-download-a-csv-file-using-phantomjs)
But I'm struggling to get a dynamic name into the ajax function

Everything else I can see talks about saving image (using render) or html (using page.open)

Surely PhantomJS has a way to save all other files?  I apprecite it's not a web spider/crawler but still?

Sorry if I'm missing something soooo obvious!

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Scrub that, after hours of searching, I find the answer minutes after posting lol

Use CasperJS wrapper, apparently file download is a known limitation

Ignore this :)