# How to execute AJAX call with PhantomJSDriver?

Tags: java, ajax, selenium, phantomjs

My test page contains a link with `onclick` making an ajax call as follows

```
 <a title="test delim" alt="" 
onclick="$find('MetricsReport').exportData('TAB');"
 href="javascript:void(0)" 
style="color: rgb(50, 50, 50); . . . ">Click to download</a>
```

When the above link is clicked, a report get downloaded to default download location.

I'm testing it with java selenium

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("$find('MetricsReport').exportData('TAB');");
```

It works fine with `ChromeDriver`, but doesn't work with `PhantomJSDriver` . No error is thrown. It kindof executes but nothing happens. The report is not downloaded

How can I make it work with `PhantomJSDriver`?

Comment: Did you try to get the element `driver.findElement("xpathOfElement")`  and then make an `element.click()`? Maybe this is a more realistic test which mimics the user interaction?!

Comment: This does not work either.

Comment: Clicking does not seem to be a trivial task in PhantomJS, check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15739263/phantomjs-click-an-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look on this question. This might solve your problem.

[How to download a csv file using PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564215/how-to-download-a-csv-file-using-phantomjs)

You can make AJAX call to download and encode your file, then you can return this content back.

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure how to implement that example. Where do I need to plug  `$find('MetricsReport').exportData('TAB');` ? Do I need to replace `$ajax . . .` with `$find` ? I'm confused because that example relies on the direct donload link `http . . . csv` which i dont have. A report on my test page downloads with the `$find` command